# Spring Boot security redirects to root after logging, I get a 404 error

Tags: spring-boot, security, redirect

I have a Spring Boot application that uses security features. My problem is that after logging in the user is redirected to the root "/" and this URI results in a 404 error. I'm running the application as autoexec.

My WebSecurityConfig class has this login configuration:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/viewExpired*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage(<login-url>).permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login.xhtml?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl(<url-not-root>)
            .and()
        .sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/viewExpired.xhtml")
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied.xhtml");
```

My web.xml contains this welcome-file block:

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And the index.html is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <!-- This url exists -->
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=pages/people/peopleList.xhtml">
</head>
</html>
```

Looks like this index.html is not loaded, that my application does not recognize the root URI (I write it as http://localhost:8090 and gives the 404).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you run your app as an executable JAR? In that case the web.xml is not used. Where is your index.html and the other pages located?

Comment: The index.html is located just under webapp folder. The rest of the pages are in a /pages subfolder. As you notice, the first problem is that my root URI is not being resolved. But anyways, if my WebSecurityConfig defined a defaultSuccessUrl pointing at a different place, shouldn't it work? Why am I landing on root folder?

Comment: Ok, the 'true' option suggested by Simon did the trick. I still had problems because I had commented the line where I disabled csfr. I uncommented it and now it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To always do a redirect you need to call:

```
.defaultSuccessUrl(<url-not-root>, true)
```

From the API Docs:

```
T   defaultSuccessUrl(String defaultSuccessUrl)
Specifies where users will go after authenticating successfully if they have not visited 
a secured page prior to authenticating.

T   defaultSuccessUrl(String defaultSuccessUrl, boolean alwaysUse)
Specifies where users will go after authenticating successfully if they have not visited 
a secured page prior to authenticating or alwaysUse is true.
```

Comment: I didn't notice this option was available. I've added it and works. Thank you!